# Using Laravel redis with same redis version on two different servers, on one the memory usage is much bigger

Tags: php, caching, redis, laravel

I am using laravel for a php project, and two days ago I wanted to move to another server. I installed everything, used the same version for everything, but when I am running my script for caching the data, on the new server it's using much more memory, and I tried to allocate three times more memory, but the script ends up with a simple message: Killed. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: 32-bit/64-bit perhaps?

Comment: 64 bits, and it is laravel 3 btw

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is issue with memory or some folder permission issue which is preventing the script from running or caching data ?